# Where is the file saved if path is not fully specified?

Tags: path, filesystems

I have this script that I run at boot using cronjob

```
#! /bin/bash
IP=$(hostname -I)
time=$(date)
echo "$time: $IP" >> IP0.log
rclone copy /home/pi/odas/IP0.log RaspberryPi:/ODAS
```

So file grabs the IP address and pipe it into `IP0.log`. My question is, without specifying the full path, where is this file saved to by default? I have googled around but I don't seem to be using the right keywords. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a user cronjob it should execute in your home directory, but I was unable to find specifics for root cronjobs. You can quickly check by writing the output of `pwd` into a file to see what the working directory is. `pwd >> pwdOutput.txt`.

Edit: Root crontab runs in `/root`.

Comment: `@reboot sleep 60 ; su pi -c "/home/pi/odas/IPupload.sh"` this is the cronjob that I run in `sudo crontab -e`. It switches to the user pi but i don't see it anywhere in my home directory. Do you think it is still ran as root?

Comment: I just checked in Ubuntu and working directory for root crontab was, unsurprisingly `/root`.

Comment: If you want your command to execute in a specific directory you can simply use `cd /path/to/directory;` before your script.

Comment: I just specified the path of that file. But thank you for the help!